# push to gitlab requires github username and password

Tags: git, gitlab

I am really new to GitLab. It would be great if you could help me with my problem.

I have a project in GitLab. I cloned it and made some changes to it. When I try to update my changes with git push (following the tutorial) in terminal (MacOS), this line pops up.

```
Username for 'https://github.com':
```

I have read some similar questions in Stack Overflow, but as far as I understand, the username and password of GitHub are only required when one tries to interact with GitHub, right? (Please forgive me if I get anything wrong).

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: What has GitLab to do with GitHub? Do you have a mirrored repository or maybe other gimmicks?

Comment: Exactly. I am so confused why my GitHub information is asked here. I don't think i have anything like that.

Comment: Are you sure you're pushing in the correct repository? If so, have you tried inserting your GitLab credentials? Maybe it's just a "print" mistake...

Comment: Please update your post with output of `git remote -v`

Comment: @j4nw thank you for you suggestion! I have checked it, I have wrongly copied the .git file of another project into the one I try to update. The problem is not solved. Thanks again!

Comment: [Please don't add "solved" to your title or question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116105/248627). Instead, [mark an answer correct by clicking on the checkmark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/248627). You can also [add your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and accept it if none of the ones you received solved your problem.

Comment: @Chris thank you. I did not know that I can mark comments as solution. :)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, pushing to either GitLab or GitHub via HTTPS will require your GitLab/GitHub username and password, otherwise anyone could push code to your repository.

If you don't want to be prompted for your credentials every time you push, you can install a credential manager and configure Git to use it. I use a MacBook Pro at work so my `.gitconfig` has this entry to store my login info:

```
[credential]
    helper = osxkeychain
```

You haven't mentioned what operating system you are using or whether you are using a GUI or command line to connect to GitLab.

Try running this command to see what remote repository your local repo is tracking:

`git remote -v`

Comment: Sorry I am using MacOS and command line to connect to GitLab. But I don't understand, why my GitHub account information is asked when i try to push to GitLab. :(

Comment: I think I understand.

You might have a URL set up for your local repositories pointing to GitHub, which pushes could be defaulting to. Have you used GitHub recently?

This might be configured in your ```.gitconfig``` or in the local repository you are trying to push.

Try running a ```git remote -v``` command to see what remote  repository your local repository is set to track.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you configured your git with GitHub credentials.
SO I Think reconfiguring your git with your Gitlab credentials may resolve your problem

Comment: If you look at all the comments under the question, you'll see it was just a case of a mis-configured remote.